# Асинхронное добавление в sqlite

Tags: android, многопоточность, sqlite

Добрый день, подскажите как с помощью потоков реализовать асинхронное добавление в базу, например 1000 записей, при этом не блокируя главный поток.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, тогда никак и SQLite поддерживает только поодиночное добавление (как альтернатива - добавление "пакетами"). Нужно использовать другую БД. И зачем вообще такое делать?

Comment: @RostislavDugin, Чтобы не получить ANR, полагаю.

Comment: @post_zeew, SQLite физически не может записывать параллельно, поэтому она будет или как-то синхронизироваться, или делать еще что-то, что заставит записывать каждый элемент отдельно. В данной ситуации лучше всего объединять все записи в пакет и записывать одним махом. Тогда на каждый запрос не будет открываться транзакция, подключение и т.д., а сделается единожды. 

Секунду это точно займет, так что такое лучше производить в фоне, по определению.

Comment: @RostislavDugin, Если я правильно понял ТС, то вопрос сводится к тому, как записывать данные в БД в потоке, отличном от UI-потока.

Comment: @post_zeew, а разве в этом есть проблема? Я почему-то не помню, чтобы вообще о таком задумывался.

Comment: @post_zeew, а... Я почему-то подумал, что он спросил о том, как их многих потоков записывать в БД с целью увеличения производительности.

Answer (score 2):

Параллельной записью из многих потоков Вы не добьетесь ничего, кроме падения производительности. **Желательно использовать один поток для записи**, в идеале, собрав все данные в пакет и записав за один раз. Потому что:

SQLite поддерживает только синхронное добавление (особенности БД). Теоретически, если Вы начнете записывать много данных из разных потоков, SQLite синхронизирует эти действия и будет записывать каждый элемент отдельно (если просто не выкинет какую-нибудь ошибку). Так на каждый элемент будет приходится отдельная транзакция, что отнимает время, а остальные потоки будут просто "висеть" и ждать, когда наступит их очередь для записи. Если Вы соберете все данные в пакет и запишете однажды, будет максимальная скорость записи из-за того, что откроется только одна транзакция. По поводу записи пакетами, смотрите документацию к Вашей ORM или библиотеке.

---

Запись в фоне можно организовать довольно большим количеством способов, вот основные:

1. [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava). Просто, изящно, удобно собирать данные в пакеты.
2. [Loader](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html?hl=ru). Android рекомендует этот класс для асинхронной записи, но он не всегда удобен, если Вы используете паттерны из разряда MVP.
3. [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Метод старый, никогда им не пользуюсь, но говорят, что и это работает, а с новыми версиями даже что-то изменилось (в лучшую сторону, разумеется).
4. [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=ru). Зависит от архитектуры приложения. Если Вы получаете данные в сервисах, то и записывать их удобнее там же.

Кстати, создавать `Thread` собственноручно очень не рекомендуется, выходит и некрасиво, и, как правило, малоэффективно.